# Find furthest and closest number to a number in array c#

Tags: c#

I have a exercise where I need to find the furthest and closest number to a certain number (average). Can somebody help me? Here is my code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Geef 10 gehele positieve getallen.");
Console.WriteLine("Getal 1:");
int g1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Getal 2:");
int g2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Getal 3:");
int g3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Getal 4:");
int g4 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Getal 5:");
int g5 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Getal 6:");
int g6 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Getal 7:");
int g7 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Getal 8:");
int g8 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Getal 9:");
int g9 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Getal 10:");
int g10 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int gemiddelde = (g1 + g2 + g3 + g4 + g5 + g6 + g7 + g8 + g9 + g10)/10;
int[] array = new int[10] {g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,g9,g10};
```

Comment: I also had to calculate the avarage of 10 numbers that the user would give me. And 'Gemiddelde' is Dutch for avarage.

Comment: What have you tried so far to find either the closest or furthest number?

Comment: Hint: any time you find yourself using variables with the same name and suffixes 1, 2, 3, ... you should be using an array or list.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree

Comment: If you are flexible on the `array` object and can use `List` instead you will have easy time implementing them using `Aggregate` for closest and furthest and `Average` for the average.

Comment: var closest = array.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs((long)x - gemiddelde)).First();                         That works but doesnt go search numbers above X so if X is 5 it only searches for numbers below 5 and not above. So if you have these numbers: 3 2 0 1 9 6 it will say that 3 is the closest number to 5 instead of saying 6

Comment: This is way too vague. Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use `List<int>` instead of array it makes things easier to code and probably cleaner depending on who you ask.

let say you change this :

```
int[] array = new int[10] {g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,g9,g10};
```

Into a list like this :

```
List<int> values = new List<int>(){g1,g2,g3,g4,g5,g6,g7,g8,g9,g10};
```

An aggregate will test each elements until the list has been completely tested.
So we can try get the closest and furthest value like so

```
// value you want to check is the average of the list.
// Average is already implemented for the List
var value = values.Average();

// will keep the closest value in the collection to our value we are looking for
// and keep testing with the following value to end up with the final closest
var closestTo = values.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(x - value) < Math.Abs(y - value) ? x : y);

// same logic as closest except we keep the furthest
var furthestTo = values.Aggregate((x, y) => Math.Abs(x - value) > Math.Abs(y - value) ? x : y);
```

Comment: This was it thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example can help you even if it is in java.

```
    //Your array with the numbers
    int[] data = {12, 123, 65, 23, 4, 213, 32, 342, 21, 15};

    int testNum = 27; //Your test value

    int holderHigh = testNum;
    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){//Goes through the array 
        //If the holder is lower than a value in the array it will get stored
        if(holderHigh < data[i]){ 
            holderHigh = data[i];
        }
    }

    int holderLow = testNum;
    for(int k = 0; k < data.length; k++){//Goes through the array 
        //If the holder is higher than a value in the array it will get stored  
        if(holderLow > data[k]){
            holderLow = data[k];
        }
    }        
    System.out.println(holderHigh + " and " + holderLow +
            " is the number farthest away from " + testNum);stNum);
```